# How to insert an icon in the beginning of a Material Text Field

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I am trying to insert an icon in the beginning of a Material Text Field. I couldn't find anything suitable in material.io's documentation as well.

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) with the `app:startIconDrawable`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="Select Time"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        ../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Note: it requires the version 1.1.0 of the library.

Comment: The `app:startIconDrawable` attribute doesn't work for me. The icon does not show up in design view, and I get an error like this: `AAPT: error: attribute app:startIconDrawable not found.` Besides this, the material component library seems to work fine.

Comment: @Nekomajin42 It requires the version 1.1.0 of the Material Components Library

Comment: @Gabrielle Mariotti Thanks! I used `1.0.0`. Updated to `1.2.0-alpha01`, but now I lost the whole material style. All I can see is the default AppCompat style on the layout design.

Comment: @Nekomajin42 I think that the 1.1.0-beta01 is better. It will become stable in a few weeks. In any case you have to use a [Material Component Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) in your app.

Comment: @Gabrielle Mariotti I tried `1.1.0-beta01` as well. Same result. I use the material component theme. Everything was fine (except the icon) with `1.0.0`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I wonder is there an option to provide `startIconDrawable` padding?

Comment: @AnoopM not currently (1.2.1-1.3.0-alpha02)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `drawableStart` attribute:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableStart

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

**step 1: copy required Text field**

Material text field doc : https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields

[image][image]
[image]

**step 2: select text field -> search "draw" -> Click drawableLeft icon**

[image]

**step 3: Select or Add icon (I'll select vector icon)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Select icon before Finish
[image]

Select icon and click OK
[image]

Done :)
[image]